# jQuery/JSON Search and Display

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve a JSON file from a server and then display the information from that dataset based on what a user searched for. Here’s what I’ve done, both conceptually and code, and would appreciate some help on either end of this.

Conceptually, I think I need to call the JSON file using jQuery/AJAX, put it into an array, and then match that data against what the user searched for and display the returned results. Eventually I’ll display the requested selection on a Google map (I have the APIs and a basic map already created).

What I don’t know:

Can I do this all in one page? I’m using WordPress and would like to just embed it in one of the WordPress pages.

Do I need to parse the data retrieved first before looping through it with jQuery.each()?

Code:

```
var items = [];

jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/e747ab91a11045e8b3f8a3efd093d3b5_0.geojson',
  success: function(data) {

    items = data.features;
    console.log(items.properties.IDENT);
    /* jQuery.each(items, function(key, value) {
    if(value.IDENT == 'LAX') { console.log(value);
    }
    })
    */
  }
});
```

For reference I am trying to call the JSON file of the FAA airports database, located here:

https://adds-faa.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/e747ab91a11045e8b3f8a3efd093d3b5_0/geoservice

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possibly off topic: not sure you want to download a **13Mb** file to a user's browser... it ain't gonna be too happy - is there a way to filter it before downloading?

Comment: Thanks. I'm open to any suggestions to improve this. Is there a way to search that file for only what you're looking for so you don't download it all?

Comment: Do you want to search all fields? or just certain fields?

Comment: Just certain fields. I can always modify later, but for now I just need some basic information (mainly name, airport codes, and latitude/longitude).

Comment: A very brief look at ArcGIS's site found this page: https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/Aviation::us-airports/geoservice which shows the various parameters one can use to query the data...

Comment: Yes, that's the same link/data as the one I posted. I guess I'm not sure how to query specific parameters when the link is to a file. I assumed that you had to call the entire file and then parse it, put it into an array, and then search it. If you can search the file directly, I'd appreciate some help with that.

Comment: Also, since you don't seem to be using anything advanced, I'd just use [`jQuery.getJSON`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) rather than ajax.

Comment: There's a link on that page to the "full [REST API documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-layer-.htm)". I have a day job, so I'm not going to comb through that; you can read, start reading :).